# Angular2 http.get from .json file: undefined error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn Angular. I read (most of) ng-book2, followed and read a lot of tutorials and articles. So I wanted to try and write a basic app and expand that later on.
BUT.. I got stuck pretty fast.
I want to read data from a .json file and display it in a list using Observables. The concept of data streams and observables is pretty abstract to me, especially since I have no programming experience besides 3yrs of basic c# school education.

So I'm trying to learn and understand by creating a simple example for myself (without an actual API), but I can't get it to work. I've searched in tons of articles and books and I got the exact same code as all their examples so I'm clearly missing something here. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Ok now for the code(I use ng-cli).
I made a model Activity and kept it simple:

```
 export class Activity {
    title: string;

    constructor(title: string){
        this.title= title;
      }
    }
```

I got 1 service and 1 component for displaying the activitylist:

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ActivityService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getActivities(): Observable<Activity[]> {
        return this.http.get('./data.json')
                        .map((res:Response)=><Activity>res.json())
                        .catch((error:any)=>Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
};
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-activity",
    template:`
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let activity of activityList">{{activity.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    `
})

export class ActivityComponent implements OnInit {

    activityList: Activity[];
    errorMessage: string;


    constructor(private activityService: ActivityService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activityService.getActivities()
                            .subscribe(
                                values=>this.activityList=values,
                                error=>this.errorMessage=<any>error);

        console.log(this.errorMessage);
    }
};
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ActivityComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [ActivityService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

data.json looks like this:

```
[
  {"title": "activiteit1"},
  {"title": "activiteit2"}
]
```

Comment: I think you need: `.map((res:Response)=><Activity[]>res.json())` since you're returning an array of objects for one, but you also need `data.json` in a location within your project that can be served by WebPack's dev server... perhaps `/src/assets/data`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/igX5dFFU7aESfzPU6qa4?p=preview  it seems to be working

Comment: Hey thank you for the replies. I used the plunk to alter my code and it works. The weird thing is that I try to recreate my error but it won't error anymore..
Basicly 3 things changed: you put the call to the get method in the constructor (is this better than to put it in ngOnInit?), the location of the json file and the writing of the subscribe.
Anyway it seems to be working now so I can continue learning!

Comment: @Brandon isn't the .map iterating through all json data which makes all parts an Activity instead of Activity[] or am I completely wrong?

Comment: `map()` simply allows you to iterate over `result` which is an array of Activity shaped objects. That's why you need to cast `res.json()` to an array of type `Activity`